# ¿Cómo corregir este error 500 al ejecutar esta petición POST en ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo problas con el siguiente codigo ajax y php, a la hora de ejercutar la peticion con ajax tira el error:

[image: error]

He probado cambiando el metodo a GET y ya no me lanza el error 500 pero no me trabaja porque estoy resiviendo en post, quiere decir que no hay problemas con la ruta.

Podrian apoyarme!!

CODIGO AJAX:

```
$('#btn-anular-pedido').click(function() {
            var conf = confirm("Esta seguro de anular el pedido");
            if (conf == true) {

                var s = "<?php echo $pedido['pago']['auditoria']; ?>";
                var pedido = "<?php echo $pedido['referencia_pedido']; ?>";
                $.ajax({
                    url: "../../resource/files/req/procesarPago.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        pedido: pedido,
                        systemTrace: s,

                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        console.log(result)
                        // var resultado = JSON.parse(result);


                        // if (resultado['ResponseCode'] == '00' && resultado['TypeOperation'] == '1') {
                        //     alert("Respuesta VISANET: " + resultado['PrivateUse63']['AlternateHostResponse22']);
                        // } else {
                        //     alert("Respuesta VISANET: " + resultado['PrivateUse63']['AlternateHostResponse22']);
                        // }
                        // setTimeout(function() {
                        //     location.reload(true);
                        // }, 1000);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("Error con el servidor...");
                    }
                });
            }

        });
```

CODIGO PHP:

```
    if (isset($_POST['systemTrace']) && isset($_POST['pedido'])) {
        echo $pago->Anulacion($_POST['systemTrace'], $_POST['pedido']);
    }
```

Comment: Que te devuelve `print_r($_POST);` ??? Sin hacer lo de los `if`

Comment: Qué sale en los logs de PHP cuando envías la petición ajax?

Comment: Los errores 500 son errores que ocurren en el servidor. Como te sugieren más arriba, revisa los logs del servidor. ¿Ese es todo el código que hay en `procesarPago.php`? Por otra parte, estas dos líneas, qué hacen ahí: `var s = "<?php echo $pedido['pago']['auditoria']; ?>";` y `var pedido = "<?php echo $pedido['referencia_pedido']; ?>";`? Eso es totalmente **contrario** al espíritu de Ajax, que sirve para separar el código en el cliente del código en el servidor. ¿Cómo se llama el archivo donde tienes el código Ajax? ¿Acaso es el mismo `procesarPago.php`?

Comment: Saludos, El código de error no es por algo en la peticion AJAX; se debe a un error durante el script PHP. Debes revisar tu log de PHP, otra opción es que cambies tu script PHP para procesar GET y pases los mismo parámetros para (acorde a tu configuración) ver en el navegador el error que se produce.